# Is there any way to forbid the son class to call the public method of super class in java?

Tags: java

Is there any way to forbid the son class to call the public method of super class in java?

For example

```
public abstract class TObject{
    abstract public void quark();
}


public class Animal extends TObject{

       public void quark(){
           System.out.println("this is the animal");
       }

}

public class Dog extends Animal{
       @overide
       public void quark(){
           System.out.println("this is the animal");
           **super.quark();**
       }
} 

In this example, The Dog call the **super.quark();** in it's quark method.
```

But I don't want the Dog could call **super.quark();** and I also don't want to change the

modifier of quark method in Animal to private. Is there any way to prevent this in compile?

I have be confused couple of days, who can help me........

The reason  I do that is  I met the similar problem in developing **hudson scm plugin**.I

created the class which extends the SubversionSCM(the offical class). I just wanted to

override the public method of super class, then call super's public method back like

example. but the compile gave error.I don't konw why, how could it do? Dose java  have

something like **reflect way**s to prevent this?

Comment: Short answer, don't do this; if you require this functionality then your design is flawed.

Comment: please post the compilation error you get.  also, please post the linee of code where the error is reported.

Answer (score 5):

No, by definition of `public` you can't stop the method from being called (whether from a derived class or anywhere else).  You can of course stop it from being *overridden* (and thereby ensure that the syntax used to call it won't use `super`;-) by making it `final`.

Comment: You can call final methods with `super`.  There's no real reason to do so, but it's allowed.

Comment: In real situation, I can't change anything in class Animal because it is written by others.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to have a public method that subclasses can't call.  The best you can do is document this recommendation.

As a note, it's called a subclass or child class.

Comment: Dose java have

something like *reflect way*s to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The other 2 answers ([Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693745/is-there-any-way-to-forbid-the-son-class-to-call-the-public-method-of-super-class/3693765#3693765) & [Matthew)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693745/is-there-any-way-to-forbid-the-son-class-to-call-the-public-method-of-super-class/3693763#3693763) are basically right.

1. you can prevent the subclass from calling a public method from the super class
2. there is probably something wrong with your design if you do this.

The below Father class has two public methods named fatherMethod.  Subclasses can call the fatherMethod using reflection (Thank You Matthew for pointing that out.)  Without using reflection, subclasses can probably not call either fatherMethod method.  Thus it is very similar to a private method.

```
class Father
{
    private class Alpha { }

    private class Beta { }

    public void fatherMethod ( Alpha param )
    {
    }

    public void fatherMethod ( Beta param )
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason why I do that is that I met the similar problem in developing hudson scm plugin.I

create the class extends the SubversionSCM(the offical class). I just want to override the

public method of super class, then call super's public method back like example. but the

compile gave error.I don't konw why, how could it do?

Dose java have something like reflect ways to prevent this?

Comment: Is the superclass method final? R U overriding it? Is it static? Is it generic? Have you double checked the parameter types? Double checked the names? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: the subperclass is not final and static ,  I could override the public method but can't call the super method in my override method..

Comment: Do u put the @Override tag on the method? I suspect u r not really overriding the public method.

Comment: If you have the @Override tag on the method and it is not really overidding the compiler will tell you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why -- "Use it every time you override a method for two benefits. Do it so that you can take advantage of the compiler checking to make sure you actually are overriding a method when you think you are. This way, if you make a common mistake of misspelling a method name or not correctly matching the parameters, you will be warned that you method does not actually override as you think it does. Secondly, it makes your code easier to understand because it is more obvious when methods are overwritten."

Comment: @emory, all of the classes in the question have a single method taking no parameters.  Yet your class has two methods, each taking an instance of a private class.  So it seems obvious you're ignoring the question in order to make a philosophical point.  In that regard you've failed.  It only requires trivial reflection to call one of the methods: `Father.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0].invoke(new Father(), new Object[]{null});`